# problem hover tieredMenu version 9 primeng

Tags: css, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using Angular and primeng verison 9.

I would like to implement hover on tiredMenu.

In the library primeNg I must click in the first moment after that I can hover on the menu to see submenu.

How can I fix that.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tieredmenu-demo-apfreg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

for the `11 to latest version` use this `<p-tieredMenu [model]="items" [autoDisplay]="'true'"></p-tieredMenu>`

Comment: Thanks for your reply; "Property autoDispaly is not provided by any applicable directive nor my tieredMenu element. I'm using prime ng version 9

Comment: @BadisMariem but you provide stackblitz which include 13 version of prime ng, please update to latest version so you can take benefit of it more feature.

Comment: Shama the same problem in all version. I should click on the item to show the subMenu.

Comment: @BadisMariem just check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tieredmenu-demo-rayx9w